# Training LSTM with web worker in Firefox doesn't work with tensorfow js

Tags: tensorflow, firefox, lstm, tensorflow.js

I am facing a quite weird problem while training LSTM layer.

Below is my model.

```
_________________________________________________________________ 
Layer (type)                 Output shape              Param #   
================================================================= 
embedding (Embedding)        [1,null,256]              131584    
_________________________________________________________________ 
lstm (LSTM)                  [1,null,1024]             5246976   
_________________________________________________________________ 
lstm_1 (LSTM)                [1,null,1024]             8392704   
_________________________________________________________________ 
dense (Dense)                [1,null,514]              526850    
=================================================================
_________________________________________________________________
```

1. Scenario 1 - No web worker, freezes the tab.
2. Scenario 2 - Training with web worker, with gfx.offscreencanvas.enabled = false. There is no activity, no error logs in the console. No callbacks are getting called.
3. Scenario 3 - Training with web worker, with gfx.offscreencanvas.enabled = true. The tab crashes, no error logs in the console. No callbacks are getting called.

Note:

In all the following scenario's inference works perfectly.

Also, the same code works in all the scenarios in chrome without any issues. So I am bit confused why does it not work on firefox.

Any help guidance in this issue will be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox is not compatible with WebWorker in many ways...

- doesn't support WebGL in web worker, usage limited to WASM
- due to WebGL memory handling, it's half the performance of Chrome when using WebGL
  (or any browser using Chromium)

Thus, I think the problem is that WebAssembly (WASM) is unable to compile the model due to lesser access to computational power.